# JSON.parse in Wordpress Backend returns error

Tags: json, wordpress, jquery

i have a dropdown list of WordPress pages with the class of 'page_id' (they repeat and can be added.. hence the livequery).  on the change event i want to send an ajax request to pull out the title, excerpt and thumbnail for the page selected.  at the moment I am just trying to get ANY kind of valid json response.  i am using json_encode in my callback to return a json object back to my .ajax function.  and then in the .ajax success function I am trying to parse this json object into something usable, but get an error every time instead.

the error seems to be a problem with JSON.parse:

```
JSON.parse
success(response="{"title":"bacon title","message":"bacon text"}0")   
handleError(a=Object { url="http://localhost/single/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", global=true, more...}, b=XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange=[xpconnect wrapped nsIDOMEventListener], readyState=4, more...}, d="success", e="{"title":"bacon title","message":"bacon text"}0")    onreadystatechange(m=readystatechange )
[Break On This Error] var json = JSON.parse(response);
```

firebug console says the response looks like:

```
{"title":"bacon title","message":"bacon text"}0
```

i don't know if that extra 0 is the trouble-maker, but i also don't know how it is getting there.  chrome reports the error as:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
$.livequery.$.change.$.ajax.success/single/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit&message=1:917
```

here is my jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.page_id').livequery(function(){ 

        var loading = $(this).next('img.ajax-loader');


        $(this).change( function() {

          var value = $(this).val();
          if (value.length) {

            $(loading).fadeIn();

            var data = {
            action: 'featured_meta_action',
            data: value,
            security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('featured-ajax-nonce'); ?>',
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                url: ajaxurl, 
                complete: function(){
                    $(loading).fadeOut();
                    },
                success: function(response){
                    var str = '{ "title": "bar" }';
                    var json = JSON.parse(response); 

                    alert(json['title']);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
          }//end if
        }); //end change

    }); //end livequery


}); //end ready
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

my php callback looks like:

```
function featured_meta_action_callback(){

    $responseVar = array(
                    'title'=>'bacon title',
                    'message'=>'bacon text',
                    );

    echo json_encode($responseVar); 

}
add_action('wp_ajax_featured_meta_action', 'featured_meta_action_callback');
```

this has turned out to be way harder than it seems like it ought to be.  i just need to get the data back from the PHP function so I can use it in the jquery.  where am i going wrong?

Comment: That 0 is the problem; it's not part of the JSON object, so jQuery can't parse the response. You need to track down what is outputting a 0 into JSON response from http://localhost/single/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

Comment: In other words, {"title":"bacon title","message":"bacon text"} is what that page should be returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be this:

```
function featured_meta_action_callback(){

    $responseVar = array(
                    'title'=>'bacon title',
                    'message'=>'bacon text' // <<< Here you do not need another comma
                    );

    echo json_encode($responseVar); 

}
```

See the comment within the array.

EDIT: Although unnecessary, in a test it doesn't output a 0 at the end of the JSON object if I leave it in there. So it's probable that it is coming from somewhere else (in other words, the WordPress code).

EDIT v2: Run these through Firebug's console. The second throws an error, but if you don't include the 0, it works just fine.

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"title":"bacon title","message":"bacon text"}'));
console.log(JSON.parse('{"title":"bacon title","message":"bacon text"}0'));
```

EDIT v3: Ok, you apparently need to short circuit the rest of the WP process by calling exit/die at the end of the function, like so:

```
function featured_meta_action_callback(){

    $responseVar = array(
                    'title'=>'bacon title',
                    'message'=>'bacon text' // <<< Here you do not need another comma
                    );

    echo json_encode($responseVar); 

    exit;
}
```

Suggested here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side

And here:

http://amiworks.co.in/talk/simplified-ajax-for-wordpress-plugin-developers-using-jquery/

Comment: @jared thanks for the reply.  i WISH it could have been this easy.  still getting that 0.  edit- just saw your other comments... it is gonna be hell tracking down that extra 0 in admin-ajax.php!  might have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: @helgatheviking - That 0 is what's causing the error (see my edit with the console.log() calls). You might edit the subject and add in a reference to WordPress, since I think that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: @helgatheviking - I added a third edit that specifies adding an exit/die call at the end of the function after you've outputted your JSON object text. This will prevent any other output that is occurring later on in the WP process, ie, whatever is adding the 0 to the end.

Comment: thanks @jared.  just saw your edits.  atleast you've helped me narrow it down, but i dont have a clue what could be generating that extra character.  le sigh.

Comment: @helgatheviking - Did you try exit/die in my v3 edit? I think the 0 is a normal response to complete the code. If you look on the codex.wordpress.org page, it says "die(); // this is required to return a proper result".

Comment: exit() and die do pretty much the same thing, and exit is a language construct, so you don't need the (), exit; works just fine.

Comment: I got it!!  - damn, i see you got it first.  i just added die(); at the end and that worked too.  thank you so much !

Comment: Cool deal. Easy enough, after all. :)